# Create users using Cloud Composer API: error 405

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-cloud-composer

I'm trying to create an Airflow user on Cloud Composer based on the [Airflow API](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/stable-rest-api-ref.html#section/Summary-of-Changes) and the [Composer API example](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/triggering-with-gcf#add_the_code_for_triggering_dags_using_airflow_rest_api). The example given in the previous link works perfectly (so the auth to the API is a success) but when using the endpoint for user creation/update it returns the following error:
`405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://...`

I use Airflow 2 on Cloud Composer so rbac UI is enabled by default.

Code:

```py
import google.auth
from google.auth.transport.requests import AuthorizedSession

AUTH_SCOPE = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
CREDENTIALS, _ = google.auth.default(scopes=[AUTH_SCOPE])


def make_composer2_web_server_request(url: str, method: str = "GET", **kwargs: Any) -> google.auth.transport.Response:
    authed_session = AuthorizedSession(CREDENTIALS)
    if "timeout" not in kwargs:
        kwargs["timeout"] = 90

    return authed_session.request(method, url, **kwargs)

def create_user(web_server_url: str) -> str:
    endpoint = f"api/v1/users"
    request_url = f"{web_server_url}/{endpoint}"
    json_data = {
        "first_name": "hello",
        "last_name": "hello",
        "username": "hello",
        "email": "mail@domain.com",
        "roles": [
            {
            "name": "Op"
            }
        ],
        "password": "password1"
    }

    response = make_composer2_web_server_request(
        request_url, method="POST", json=json_data
    )
    return response.text
```

Any idea?

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: I answered you on your post

Answer (score 1):

This type or error is about permissions with the user you are using.

For Cloud Composer you can use these roles to view, create, update, upgrade, and delete environments, manage objects (such as DAG files) in the environment buckets, and access the Airflow web interface:

- Environment and Storage Object Administrator
- Service Account User

To view environments, access the Airflow web interface, and manage objects in the environment buckets (to upload new DAG files):

- Environment User and Storage Object Viewer
- Storage Object Admin

You can see more documentation about [Cloud Composer permissions](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control#user-account).

You can use more granular permissions. Here are some examples:

- Environments.create
- Operations.get

You can see more granular permissions in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/how-to/access-control#permissions).

If you want to manage the permission of the DAGs, you can see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/airflow-rbac#assigning_dags_to_roles_in_dag_properties).

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I figured out that the version of the Airflow API I used (2.1.4)  has no endpoints for editing/creating new users. 2.1.4 is the last version of Airflow supported at date in Cloud composer so it it currently not possible to make those actions. Instead, we can use the gcloud commands